# Modify "View Member Email Addresses" Setting

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-groups-settings

Is there a way to modify the "View Member Email Addresses" settings via the google admin API? From some cursory investigation this doesn't seem to be the case but I'd be happy to be proven wrong. Note that this setting is different than the existing whoCanViewMembership setting.

Answer (score 0):

Right now this is not possible. The [group settings documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/v1/reference/groups#resource) lists the available settings and "View Member Email Addresses" is not listed. There's no alternative API as far as I am aware.

```
{
  "kind": "groupsSettings#groups",
  "email": string,
  "name": string,
  "description": string,
  "whoCanAdd": string,
  "whoCanJoin": string,
  "whoCanViewMembership": string,
  "whoCanViewGroup": string,
  "whoCanInvite": string,
  "allowExternalMembers": string,
  "whoCanPostMessage": string,
  "allowWebPosting": string,
  "primaryLanguage": string,
  "maxMessageBytes": integer,
  "isArchived": string,
  "archiveOnly": string,
  "messageModerationLevel": string,
  "spamModerationLevel": string,
  "replyTo": string,
  "customReplyTo": string,
  "includeCustomFooter": string,
  "customFooterText": string,
  "sendMessageDenyNotification": string,
  "defaultMessageDenyNotificationText": string,
  "showInGroupDirectory": string,
  "allowGoogleCommunication": string,
  "membersCanPostAsTheGroup": string,
  "messageDisplayFont": string
  "includeInGlobalAddressList": string,
  "whoCanLeaveGroup": string,
  "whoCanContactOwner": string,
}
```